# reset_password_instructions.html.erb uses what layout

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I'm using Rails and Devise for user management.
I'd like all my emails to be consistent in style and modify  of Devise password reset email.

`reset_password_instructions.html.erb` features only contents of the . There has to be a layout it uses somewhere, but I cannot find it...

Answer (score 0):

You can define a layout for all Devise mail using an initializer.

config/initializer/devise.rb

```
Devise.setup do |config|

  # Other options here...

  config.to_prepare do
    Devise::Mailer.layout "email" # email.haml or email.erb
  end
end
```

https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Create-custom-layouts

You would have to create a new email layout with the name you identified in `Devise::Mailer.layout` but that's a good thing since now you have complete control over the code.